# Javascript function calling after the executing function finishes

Tags: javascript, function

I am working on google Maps API.  I dont know why the below function is being called after the index++. As far as I know ReverseGeocode() should be called first.  Instead of that it is first incrementing and then calling the function which is creating problems for me.  The alert boxes are shown as they are written but the middle function is called after the last line of the function is executed i.e (index++).

```
      function placeMarker(location)
      {
          alert("iiii");
          ReverseGeocode(location.lat(),location.lng());
          alert("jjjk");
          index++;
      }
```

Here is my ReverseGeoCode

```
  function ReverseGeocode(lat,lng) {     
     var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
     geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status)
  {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) 
     {
           if (results[1])
      {

          places[index]=results[0].formatted_address;
          alert(places[index]+"index="+index);
          AddRow('table',results[0].formatted_address);
          document.getElementById("dataa").innerHTML+=results[0].formatted_address+"<br/>";
      }
  }
  else 
  {
    alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
      }
    });
  }
```

Please Explain. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post your **ReverseGeocode** function?

Comment: How do you determine that `ReverseGeoCode` executes after `index++`?

Comment: @deestan look at the reversegeocode function i've placed an alertbox in it.the alertbox shows the index value as 1 and i've defined it globally as 0.So when the first time function is called the alert box shows me the index value of 1

Comment: Is `geocoder.geocode` asynchronous?

Comment: you could add a callback as a third arg to your `GeoCode` function and execute it at the end of the function; then you can pass any dependent operations such as your `index` increment into the callback.

Comment: The `ReverseGeocode()` function is executing before `index++`, but what it does is call `geocoder.geocode()` which is asynchronous so the callback function you pass to `.geocode()` doesn't get executed until later. Given that `index` is not a local variable can't you just increment it at the end of the callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alert is inside your callback function, which will execute when `geocoder.geocode` finishes its calculation.

`geocoder.geocode` appears to asynchronous.  Usually, this means `geocoder.geocode` will start plodding along with its work somewhere else, while your program continues to its local conclusion.  When `geocoder.geocode` later finishes, it will execute your supplied callback function.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the `geocoder.geocode` is asynchronous. It is executing your anonymous function somethime later, when the value of `index` has incremented.

```
function placeMarker(location)
 {
 alert("iiii")
 ReverseGeocode(location.lat(),location.lng(),index);
 alert("jjjk");
 index++;
```

}

```
function ReverseGeocode(lat,lng,index) {     
     var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
     geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status)
  {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) 
     {
           if (results[1])
      {

          places[index]=results[0].formatted_address;
          alert(places[index]+"index="+index);
          AddRow('table',results[0].formatted_address);
          document.getElementById("dataa").innerHTML+=results[0].formatted_address+"<br/>";
      }
  }
  else 
  {
    alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
      }
    });
  }
```

In this case, `index` goes into the local scope of the anonymous function, so it is not overwritten.